# Dafny copy multiset data into array

Tags: dafny

I am new to Dafny. I am writing a programme to FindMax. By going through [this tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial), I am able to write the verified programme for arrays.

```
method FindMax(a: array<int>) returns (i: int)

  requires 0<a.Length
  ensures 0<= i < a.Length
  ensures  forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] <= a[i]
   // Annotate this method with pre- and postconditions
   // that ensure it behaves as described.
{
   // Fill in the body that calculates the INDEX of the maximum.

  i:=0;
   var index := 0;
   while index < a.Length
      invariant 0 <= index <= a.Length
      invariant 0 <= i < a.Length
      invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < index ==> a[k] <= a[i]

      {
      if a[index] > a[i] {
      i := index;
      }
      index := index + 1;
   }
}
```

Now I want to write a similar programme when data is in the form of Multiset. As .length function is not allowed in multiset, it's giving error.
Another approach I thought is to convert multiset data into arrays -> apply operation and convert back.
Now I am stuck into writing function to convert multiset data into arrays.
I read this [tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Collections) but still facing difficulties due to limited documentation and being new to Dafny.
Any help or resource link will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who might visit this answer later - all you need to do is use |a| at the place of a.length and the same method would correctly work for multiset